# tar --files-from complains "Cannot stat: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, tar, stat

When I type " tar -cvf ~/changeset.tar --files-from ~/changeset.txt", It responds with this output: http://pastie.org/1071080. Here is the contents of ~/changeset.txt: http://pastie.org/1071084 . In other words, a bunch of relative paths. As a sanity check,

$ ls admin/memberinformation.php admin/memberinformation.php

Why can't tar find any of these files even though they are clearly reachable from the current directory with the relative paths given?

FYI: $ tar --version tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is the position of the colon in the `tar` output.

You've got a bad case of the trailing spaces.  Get rid of them in your changeset file.